# Use Devise helper methods in decorators in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a a decorator in my Rails 4 project:`app/decorators/course_decorator.rb`

Inside `course_decorator.rb`, I want to define a method that will display a link if a condition is satisfied.
For instance, I am doing:

```
class CourseDecorator

def initialize(course)
  @course = course
end

def view_button
  if user_signed_in?
    link_to "View", @course
  end
end
```

I am using Devise gem for user authentication, and `user_signed_in?` is a helper provided by Devise.

When trying to use the `view_button` method in my view, I get no method error. The error is something in the lines of `undefined method 'user_signed_in?' for #Course:0x007fcc7ccb8310`

I think this is happening because decorator is calling `user_signed_in?` method on Course object. How can I properly implement `user_signed_in?` method in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Devise wiki [here](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/test-helpers):

Devise includes some test helpers for functional specs. In order to use them, you need to include Devise in your functional tests by adding the following to the bottom of your

```
test/test_helper.rb file:

class ActionController::TestCase  
  include Devise::TestHelpers  
end
```

If you're using RSpec, you can put the following inside a file named spec/support

```
/devise.rb or in your spec/spec_helper.rb:  

RSpec.configure do |config|  
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller  
end
```